# Woocommerce products list - replace <ul><li> to bootstrap div

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce, hook, action

I looking for all day, a proper solution for make woocommerce template with bootstrap grid. Always i tried make changes with hooks because i think its the best way.

**Woocommerce display products list like this:**

```
<ul class="products">

<li class="post-24 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-zupki-z-chin product_tag-test first instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple"></li>

<li class="post-30 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-zupki-z-chin  instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple"></li>

<li class="post-31 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-zupki-z-chin  instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple"></li>

<li class="post-32 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-zupki-z-chin last instock shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple"></li>

</ul>
```

**I would like change this to proper bootstrap grid.
Something like that:**

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md3">product</li>

<div class="col-md3">product</li>

<div class="col-md3">product</li>

<div class="col-md3">product</li>

</ul>
```

Change ul to div its possible by function woocommerce_product_loop_start(), but how can I change/replace **li class="....**  to **div class="col-md....** ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 8):

So you will want to overwrite a woocommerce template file with a template file in your child theme.

FTP into your install, go to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates`, copy content-product.php, duplicate that file in your child theme in a new folder called 'woocommerce'.

Then change the `<ul <?php post_class(); ?>>` to your div and whatever class you want.

If you have questions about overriding woocommerce template files check this out: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256088/how-to-override-woocommerce-template-files

Answer (score 5):

You can change `<ul>` without editing template, just use this in functions.php:

```
/** 
 * Add Custom WooCommerce Loop Start
 */
function woocommerce_product_loop_start( $echo = true ) {
    ob_start();
    echo '<div class="something">'; 
    if ( $echo )
        echo ob_get_clean();
    else
        return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Comment: This answer is nice, because the less you mess with template files, the less you have to update down the road when Woo decides to warn anyone who can login to /wp-admin/ that "Your theme has outdated versions of template files." But it would be even nicer if you included how to change the closing `ul` to a `div` as well. Using this code alone will not do that.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to change it is to overriding woocomerce templates.

The Ul tag is generated by `loop-start.php`.

You can find it on:

> `content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/loop-start.php`.

if you want to change the loop start and loop end you have to copy the files:

> `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/loop/loop-start.php`

into your themes folder:

> `wp-content/themes/mysuperchildtheme/woocommerce/loop/`